# EXEC_BAD_ACESS for retained object

Tags: ios, xcode4

I am using xCode 4.3 and this is weird. I have properly initialized my UITextfield but when i call it in IBAction it gives me EXEC_BAD_ACCESS>

```
in .h File
interface .........
{
IBOutlet UITextField * usernameField;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField * usernameField;

in .m File

@implementaion ............

@synthesize usernameField;

- (IBAction) editingEnded:(id)sender
{

    [usernameField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: daft question but is the usernamefield hooked up in interface builder?

Comment: Yes it is and I have attached Did End on Exit event to the IBAction, But When i presss 'return' it just crash

Comment: If it even crashes on code containing a log statement only then it's nothing to do with the text field ivar, your problem is that whatever object the above code is in has been released (the textfield wont retain it's delegate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your property should have iboutlet on it to.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField * usernameField;
```

does that solve the problem?

Comment: Just Tried , which should not matter but still crashing

Comment: Can you try changing it from [usernameField resignFirstResponder] to [id resignFirstResponder] see if that works.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Pretty new to IOS. It might be worth trying [self.usernameField resignFirstResponder]

Comment: When you put IBAction on the property did you remove it from the instance variable, and then reconnect in the nib.

Comment: Weird thig is that even   `code` - (IBAction) editingEnded:(id)sender
{

   NSlog(@"test");
} crashes

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should implement the [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate), this way you can manage the event when the user "Ends Editing" trough the delegate's methods. If I understand correctly, what you want to do is to "Resign First Responder" so I suggest you to do the following:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{ 
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; 
    return NO;
}
```